# Counting the number of Total CounterExamples in Alloy

Tags: alloy

Calling the

```
Kodkod.execute()
```

method returns a ***A4Soluiton*** object, which we can iterate by ***next()*** method until it reaches to a counterexample which is ***unsatisfiable()***. By this way we can count the total number of counterexamples by the solver.

My question is, if it is possible to know the total number of counterexamples directly from the ***A4Solution*** object without iterating through it.

Thanks a lot in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the total number of counterexamples ahead of time, i.e., without enumerating one by one.

Comment: Do you know how it works internally? As I guess, the solution object returned by the **Kodkod.execute()** contains all the counterexamples. In other words, calling **next()** on the solution object doesn't execute the command to find a new counterexample, it rather traverses on the solution object. Am I correct?

Comment: No, the solution returned from Kodkod contains only a single counterexample, so it does have to execute the same command again to find new ones.  It simply adds a new constraint to the existing model to ensure that the subsequent solutions (counterexamples) are different from the current one, and then re-runs the solver (i.e., `Kodkod.execute()`)

Comment: In Alloy Graphical Interface, when an assertion is executed the result show two time figure as below.

`2937 vars. 1008 primary vars. 5676 clauses. 555ms.
    Counterexample found. Assertion is invalid. 117ms.`

Do you know what does this two time figures mean? Do I need to 
sum up these two figures to calculate the total time for a counterexample?

Comment: Yes.  The first number (555ms) is the *translation time* (time it takes Alloy and Kodkod to translate the model to CNF), and the second number (117ms) is the *solving time* (time it takes the SAT solver to find a solution for the translated CNF formula)